# Facebook Connect login not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook

Im having a problem using Facebook Connect on my latest website. Im running it using the CodeIgniter framework and Elliot Haughin's library (http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/).

Everything is setup okay, when the user goes to login, the request is sent to Facebook okay and returns with the code (which i presume identifies the session?).

However, it doesnt seem to update the library, and after doing all this still thinks that the user is not logged in. It makes me think its a bug in the library itself, but I can't see anyone else with this problem.

I have tried dumping the error log from the library but it doesnt find any problems.

If someone could shed any light I would be so grateful!

Comment: You should provide more details about the issue, such as the code you are using, and what you have tried already.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. It's a lot of code spread across multiple files. It really takes someone who's worked with it before to know what's going on. Im just wondering if anyone can think of a reason as to why it wouldnt store the session. The code must be alright if hundreds of other people have used the library, is there any settings that might conflict? Thanks.

Comment: Ive tried adding in the Javascript SDK in case it requires that to work and Ive also added in the FBML header, but its still not storing the session. This was a longshot, surely PHP should run solely by itself and not in correlation with another language.

Comment: It's also worth noting that using HTML5 Local Storage the connection has been successfully established, its just the PHP backend thats not reading something right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented facebook connect without any library just following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/) and breaking the code into a model and controller. It worked fine for me, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Elliot Haughin's library.  Solution:

Change `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']` to `TRUE` in `config.php` and it works.